# Type hinting methods called from builder method

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm, type-hinting

Consider an Active Record implementation which uses a static builder to return instances of a model. Here is a very **reduced** version of the ModelBuilder and Model classes to demonstrate, with all code irrelevant to the question removed:

```
class ModelBuilder {
    public function __construct($class) {
        $this->class = $class
    }

    private function _execute() {
        $result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM {$this->class}");
        return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $this->class);
    }

    public function all() {
        return $this->_execute();
    }

    public function one() {
        return $this->_execute()[0];
    }
}

class Model {
    public static function builder() {
        return new ModelBuilder(get_called_class());
    }
}

class FooModel extends Model {

}
```

To get a Foo item we call the FooModel class like this:

```
$foo = FooModel::builder()->one();
```

In this case intelligent IDEs (in my case PhpStorm) do not know what type of object `$foo` is. I could type-hint the variable `/** @var $foo FooModel */` each time I create an object but I would prefer proper type-hinting on the `all()` and `one()` methods.

**What is the proper type hinting to add to the `all()` and `one()` methods?** Note that `static` does not work, I believe because ModelBuilder is not an ancestor of the initial called class and it is being called explicitly in the `builder()` method.

This particular project is using PHP 5.6, but answers that are PHP 7 specific are welcome as well.

Comment: You can't. Adding that commend is the only viable option. Of course, I would recommend also stayong avay from active record anti-pattern, but that's just my silly notion about OOP and SRP.

Comment: @tereško: I would appreciate hearing your arguments against the ActiveRecord pattern, as I use it often. I'd like to learn a better way.

Comment: The better persistence pattern to use is called "[data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)", but there are also thing like "table data gateway" (what some people have a bad habit of describing as "repository", even though its not that). And the main reason for avoiding AR is performance.

Answer (score 1):

If your models have parent class like `BaseModel` - you can use `BaseModel` in return block inside doc-block for `all` and `one` methods, like:

```
/**
* @return BaseModel Model instance.
*/
public function one() {
    return $this->_execute()[0];
}
```

But in this case - it is just `BaseModel` it is not `FooModel` nor `BooModel`...

You will have access only to BaseModel methods and properties, but not to FooModel specific...

With purpose to have certain model - you have override needed method in child model with proper doc-block, like:

```
class FooModel extends BaseModel
{
    /**
    * @return FooModel Foo model instance.
    */
    public function one() {
        return parent::one();
    }
}
```

Or have doc-block for class, like this:

```
/**
 * @method FooModel one Foo model instance.
 */
class FooModel extends BaseModel
{
}
```

Or use doc-block `/** @var $foo FooModel */` like you've already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I am looking for a way to have the `FooModel` properties available, not just those for `Model`, and I would like to avoid overriding the method in each extended class just for type hinting. I suppose that it's either the override or I'll have to stick to the doc blocks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, added example `@method FooModel one Foo model instance.` You can have this block for `FooModel` class, so you don't have to override `one` method.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I didn't know about the `@method` typehinting on the class. Nice! It won't work here, though, as `one()` is a method of the `ModelBuilder` class, not `Model`.